# MVP + Interactors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Given the following flow:

[image]

I want the methods to be executed by these threads:

- `OnClick` (by system) : ui
- `OnRefresh` (1) : ui
- `ReadDb` (2) : worker
- `SetData`(3) : ui

I could achieve this by making `ReadDb` *async* and *await*ing it, but it would freeze the UI thread.

Can you think of an approach that doesn't involve implementing `Interactors`, `AsyncTask` etc. ?

Thanks.

---

**Edit**

I am looking for an elegant solution, please avoid having wrappers like `new Handler (Looper.getMainLooper()).post(...)`, `RunOnUiThread` in every method of the `View` etc.

The easiest approach is to use `taskt` and `await`:

```
async OnRefresh() {
    data = await m.ReadDb() 
    v.SetData(data)
}
```

However, the UI freezes on `await m.ReadDb()`. I thought that because `OnRefresh` returns `void` it would go back and finish executing the parent method (`OnClick`). Then, once the `await` is done, it would exeute `v.SetData(d)`. For some reason, it's not the output I am getting.

Comment: Why it needs to await for it? you can do `ReadDb` async and once the data is loaded send it to MainThread and do v.setData ...

Comment: @SabaJafarzadeh What do you mean by `send it to MainThread` ?

Comment: means to run it on ui thread. (by `Handler(Looper.gerMainLooper()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my approach was correct, but the implementation is not right. I was expecting `await m.ReadDb()` to be run in a worker thread, but it wasn't. The reason for this, is that I had to explicitly ask for it with `Task.Run` and `await` it:

```
OnRefresh() 
{
    var d = await Task.Run (() => m.ReadDb());
    v.SetData(d)
}
```

Just writing `await` doesn't create a new thread, that's why the UI was being blocked.

Check [my other question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133967/async-method-freezes-ui/), where it was pointed out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class View {
    IPresenter p;

    void onClick() {
        p.OnRefresh()
    }

    void setData() {

    }
}

class Presenter implements Listener {
    void OnRefresh() {
        // You can do it with newThread or anything that does async
        async (
            m.readDB()
        )
    }

    void onComplete(Data data) {
        // or you can put it on Model class.
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            // this will be run on ui (or main) thread.
            v.setData(data);
        })
    }
}

class Model {

    Listener lstr;

    void readDB() {
        // read data..

        // completed
        lstr.onComplete(data)
    }
}

interface Listener {
    void onComplete(Data data)
}
```

You can also add onFailure() and other methods, also RxJava makes this so much simpler take a look at that.

Note: another thing that you need to be worried here is circular references causing by View having a ref to presenter and presenter having a ref to view. you need manually destroy the ref once you no longer need it (onDestroy probably) or memory leak would happen.

Comment: Thanks Saba, unfortunately, I don't like this approach. I don't want to have `Listeners` for each call I do to the `Model`, nor the `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(()` boilerplate code everywhere. I will make that clear in the post for other people too.